# How to rename db columns of linking table (many to many realiton) in ASP .NET MVC EF (code first)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need to create this db context:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Contact> Employers { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Contact> Staff { get; set; }
}
```

EF creates the table ContactContacs with columns Contact_ID and Contact_ID1. How (where) can I rename this context columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `DbContext`'s `OnModelCreating()` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().HasMany(x => x.Employers).WithMany().Map(x =>
{
    x.ToTable("ContactEmployers");
    x.MapLeftKey("ContactId");
    x.MapRightKey("EmployerId");
});
```

- `modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()` => The model you're configuring
- `HasMany(x => x.Employers)` => Indicates it's a many-to-X relationship with a navigation property
- `WithMany()` => Configures it as a many-to-many relationship without a navigation property on the other side
- `Map()` => Configuring the table and columns for the IDs

Comment: I use migrations. I should do it in this way?

Comment: Yes. This is simple fluent mapping.